# DataView Rowfilter - Escape single quote wrapped inside single quotes

Tags: c#, datatable, dataview, rowfilter

In my application the user can manually build the rowfiler. An example of this would be

```
(Message LIKE '%'[Search]'%') OR (Message LIKE '%'[Search2]'%')
```

How would I escape this? Currently I use the function below to escape the brackets and any slashes but I need somewhere of escaping single quotes inside the whole filter string.

```
public static string CheckValue(string value) { StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    string pattern = @"([-\]\[<>\?\*\\\""/\|\~\(\)\#/=><+\%&\^\'])";

    Regex expression = new Regex(pattern);

    if (expression.IsMatch(value))
    {
        foreach (char c in value)
        {
            switch(c){
                case '\\':
                     sBuilder.Append("\\");
                    break;
                case '[':
                    sBuilder.Append(@"[[]");
                    break;
                case ']':
                    sBuilder.Append(@"[]]");
                    break;
                default: 
                    sBuilder.Append(c);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return sBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape single quote

```
sBuilder.Append(@"\'");
```

Comment: Doing that breaks query as it also escapes the start and end rowfilter quotes.